# "As is" or "as Are"

Tags: grammar, grammatical-number

Which of the following is correct?

> Your behavior is unacceptable, as **are** immature remarks.
>
> Your behavior is unacceptable, as **is** immature remarks.

I want to understand what's going on grammatically.

Comment: Proofreading questions are off topic because they do not help anyone but the asker. The only exception is when there is a clearly identified source of concern about an element of the English language that would be interesting and useful to many future visitors.

Comment: Off topic, but there is more than one remark, so 'as are' is correct here.

Comment: Voting to reopen.  This question is about grammar, not proofreading.